# Trigger - SQL Statement ignored, ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Function of trigger: Trigger that updates the order_info table
whenever a new record is inserted into purchased.  If there is already an entry in the order_info
table for this custnum/pdate combination, update the address and increase the order_total by
the amount of this widget.  Otherwise, create a new record in order_total with the custnum,
pdate, and address, and an order_total equal to the price of the widget that was just purchased.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_order_info
AFTER INSERT ON purchased
REFERENCING NEW AS new_row OLD AS old_row
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
match Int;
BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO match
        FROM order_info
        WHERE order_info.custnum = :new_row.custnum, order_info.pdate = :new_row.pdate
        IF match = 1 THEN
            UPDATE order_info
            SET order_info.address = ( SELECT address
                                       FROM customer
                                       WHERE customer.custnum = :new_row.custnum ),
            SET order_info.order_total = order_info.order_total + ( SELECT price
                                                                    FROM widget
                                                                    WHERE widget.stocknum = :new_row.stocknum )
        
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO order_info
            order_info VALUES ( :new_row.custnum, :new_row.pdate, ( SELECT price
                                                                    FROM widget
                                                                    WHERE widget.stocknum = :new_row.stocknum )
                                , ( SELECT address
                                    FROM customer
                                    WHERE customer.custnum = :new_row.custnum ))
        END IF;
END;
```

Error:

```
Errors: TRIGGER TRIGGER_ORDER_INFO
Line/Col: 6/9 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 9/52 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Tables

```
create table customer (
    custnum int primary key,
    name varchar2(50) not null, 
    address varchar2(50)
);
 
create table employee (
    ssn char(9) primary key,
    name varchar2(50) not null, 
    address varchar2(50),
    salary numeric(10,2)
);
 
create table widget (
    stocknum int primary key,
    manufacturer varchar2(50) not null,
    description varchar2(50) not null,
    weight real,
    price numeric(10,2),
    inventory int not null
);
 
create table purchased (
    custnum int,
    stocknum int, 
    pdate date,
    primary key (custnum, stocknum, pdate),
    foreign key (custnum) references customer,
    foreign key (stocknum) references widget
);
 
create table newitem (
    stocknum int primary key,
    manufacturer varchar2(50) not null,
    description varchar2(50) not null
);
 
create table requestedby (
    custnum int,
    stocknum int, 
    primary key (custnum, stocknum),
    foreign key (custnum) references customer,
    foreign key (stocknum) references newitem
);
 
CREATE TABLE order_info (
custnum int,
pdate date,
order_total int,
address varchar2(50),
PRIMARY KEY (custnum, pdate, order_total, address),
FOREIGN KEY (custnum, order_total, pdate) REFERENCES purchased);
 
 
insert into customer values (1,'Alice','100 Elm St');
insert into customer values (2,'Bob','10 Main St');
insert into customer values (3,'Chuck','1000 Oak St');
insert into customer values (4,'Dave','2000 Pine St');
insert into customer values (5,'Eve','3000 Maple St');
insert into customer values (6,'Harry','100 Elm St');
 
insert into employee values ('123456789','Alice','100 Elm St', 40000.00);
insert into employee values ('444444444','Isabella','100 Elm St', 40000.00);
insert into employee values ('222222222','Frank','4000 Tulip Ave', 30000.00);
insert into employee values ('333333333','Geena','50 Flower Ave', null);
 
insert into widget values (101, 'Acme Corp.', 'Thingamajig', 1, 10, 3);
insert into widget values (201, 'Seuss Inc.', 'Thing 1', 14, 16, 5);
insert into widget values (202, 'Seuss Inc.', 'Thing 2', 13, 12, 10);
insert into widget values (301, 'SH Rock', 'Noun', null, null, 0);
 
insert into purchased values (1, 101, DATE '2021-1-10');
insert into purchased values (1, 101, DATE '2021-2-12');
insert into purchased values (1, 201, DATE '2021-3-13');
insert into purchased values (1, 202, DATE '2021-4-15');
insert into purchased values (1, 202, DATE '2021-5-15');
insert into purchased values (2, 101, DATE '2021-5-16');
insert into purchased values (3, 101, DATE '2021-6-17');
insert into purchased values (3, 101, DATE '2021-6-18');
insert into purchased values (3, 101, DATE '2021-6-19');
insert into purchased values (4, 201, DATE '2021-7-18');
insert into purchased values (3, 202, DATE '2021-8-19');
insert into purchased values (6, 301, DATE '2022-1-19');
insert into purchased values (6, 202, DATE '2022-2-19');
insert into purchased values (6, 202, DATE '2022-2-20');
insert into purchased values (6, 202, DATE '2022-2-21');
 
insert into newitem values (101, 'Acme Corp.', 'Thingamajig');
insert into newitem values (201, 'Seuss Inc.', 'Thing 1');
insert into newitem values (500, 'SH Rock', 'verb');
 
insert into requestedby values (5, 500);
insert into requestedby values (5, 201);
insert into requestedby values (6, 101);

CREATE TABLE order_info (
custnum int,
pdate date,
order_total int,
address varchar2(50),
PRIMARY KEY (custnum, pdate, order_total, address),
FOREIGN KEY (custnum, order_total, pdate) REFERENCES purchased);
```

Comment: it's not a good idea to violate the normalization rules by adding such a column like `order_total` which is already could be derived from the data source through a select statement(or a stored select statement like sql-view or materialized view).

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax, mostly, e.g.

- superfluous `SET` keyword,
- missing comma,
- missing semi-colon (as statement terminator),
- superfluous table name in `insert`

When fixed, query looks like this (can't test it, I don't have your tables):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_order_info
  2    AFTER INSERT ON purchased
  3    REFERENCING NEW AS new_row OLD AS old_row
  4    FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6    match Int;
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT COUNT(*)
  9    INTO match
 10    FROM order_info
 11    WHERE order_info.custnum = :new_row.custnum
 12      AND order_info.pdate = :new_row.pdate;
 13
 14    IF match = 1 THEN
 15       UPDATE order_info
 16          SET order_info.address = ( SELECT address
 17                                     FROM customer
 18                                     WHERE customer.custnum = :new_row.custnum ),
 19              order_info.order_total = ( SELECT price + order_info.order_total
 20                                         FROM widget
 21                                         WHERE widget.stocknum = :new_row.stocknum );
 22    ELSE
 23      INSERT INTO order_info
 24        VALUES ( :new_row.custnum, :new_row.pdate,
 25                 ( SELECT price
 26                   FROM widget
 27                   WHERE widget.stocknum = :new_row.stocknum )
 28               , ( SELECT address
 29                   FROM customer
 30                   WHERE customer.custnum = :new_row.custnum ));
 31    END IF;
 32  END;
 33  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mUFy73Qy

Added tables. Can you help to troubleshoot the trigger code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't download anything from unknown sources. It would be better if you edited the original message and posted CREATE TABLE statements there.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: OK; I also edited the answer and actually *executed* that CREATE TRIGGER statement; it seems to be OK, no errors (which is what you'd see for yourself, only if you ran it).